# Excel - Comparing the value of 2 fields (version number)

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to compare and check version numbers and I am not able to use any of the comparison operators because possible examples are

```
2.0
3.1a
2.1c
3.11d
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: So `A1=B1` or `EXACT(A1,B1)` do not work?

Comment: Are you trying to do less/greater than comparisons? Please provide more information on what you're trying to do.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to do less/greater comparisons.   They are version numbers so I want  to find the "latest" version

Comment: `=A2<A3` works for me: https://imgur.com/a/DaLtBGs

Comment: Any chance using a help column with regular numeric values? Do you have a finite version list that can just be ordered alphabetically? If not, is the versioning predictable somehow?

Comment: Can we assume that v3.11 is newer than v3.7?

Answer (score 2):

This problem is deceptively complicated.  I'll lay out some of the component factors to illustrate what must be considered.  The solution uses a helper column containing a translation of the version number that can be properly sorted or evaluated.  The image below is for explanation purposes, the actual solution is at the end.

[image]

In Column A is a list of version numbers.  Notice that versions without a letter at the end can be interpreted as numbers.  That isn't necessarily a problem unless the version translates to an integer.  For example, version 2.0 might end up as simply `2`, in which case the solution must be more complex to provide a way to compare the values.  This solution starts with the premise that all of the version designations are stored as text.

Version numbers and sub-numbers often go into double digits.  This means that the components of the version can't be parsed just by character position in the version string.

It also means that sub-numbers can't be sorted by normal means.  This example includes versions 3.7 and 3.11.  Normal sorting would say that 3.7 is the higher number, but 3.11 is actually the newer version.

And, of course, the issue that brought the question -- versions ending with a letter; how to sort a mix of numbers and letters.

Breaking the problem down, I've included the needed components in this example to make it easier to follow.  Each component is simple, but combining them into a single formula gets hard to follow.

**Decimal Location**

Parsing the version number starts with where the decimal is located.  If there can only ever be a single-digit major version number, this will always be position 2 in the version string.  If the version can go into double digits, this formula in column B will do it:

```
=FIND(".",A2)
```

**Portion left of decimal**

The portion to the left of the decimal needs to be handled separately from the portion to the right.  Since the version can contain a letter, we can't just take the integer.  The location of the decimal point can be used to peel off the integer portion (column C in the example):

```
=LEFT(A2,B2-1)
```

**Sub-version number**

Parsing the sub-version number depends on whether there is a letter at the end.  This is column D, found by:

```
=CODE(RIGHT(A2,1))>57
```

This uses the ASCII code to evaluate the last character.  Numbers end at ASCII character 57, so anything higher used in the version designation will be a letter.

Column E shows parsing the sub-version number:

```
=MID(A2,B2+1,LEN(A2)-B2-D2)
```

It takes the middle of the string, starting with the character after the decimal point, and a length equal to the length of the whole string minus the portion through the decimal point, and potentially minus the character at the end.  For the character at the end, it uses the Boolean value (`0` or `1`) of the True/False determination of whether it ends with a letter.

The sub-version number needs to be expressed to a uniform number of places by adding a fill zero for single-digit values.  One way this is often done is with the TEXT function.  However, at least in LO Calc, this doesn't work properly for a value of zero.  So the formula used in column F:

```
=REPT("0",2-LEN(A2)+B2+D2)&E2
```

This creates a repetition of `0` for the number of "missing places" and then concatenates the sub-version number from the last step.

**Ending letter**

In order to sort the version number, any letter on the end is converted to its ASCII code (a filler value of zero, ASCII 48, is added as a placeholder if there is no letter.  I used this instead of ASCII 00 because the ASCII number can be three digits, and this must be filled with a leading zero for two-digit codes.  As with the sub-version number, this would have complicated things.  The formula for the filled last character in column G:

```
=TEXT(IF(CODE(RIGHT(A2,1))>57,CODE(RIGHT(A2,1)),48),"0##")
```

In this case, the TEXT function can be used to add the fill zero.

**Sortable value**

The sort value is built from these components in column H:

```
=VALUE(C2&F2&G2)
```

This concatenates the three parts and then converts the result to a number.  This can be done in a single step by substituting cell formulas for cell references, which gives you this as the helper column formula:

```
=VALUE(LEFT(A2,FIND(".",A2)-1)&REPT("0",2-LEN(A2)+FIND(".",A2)+(CODE(RIGHT(A2,1))>57))&MID(A2,FIND(".",A2)+1,LEN(A2)-FIND(".",A2)-(CODE(RIGHT(A2,1))>57))&TEXT(IF(CODE(RIGHT(A2,1))>57,CODE(RIGHT(A2,1)),48),"0##"))
```

### Solution

The solution then looks like this:

[image]

**Finding the latest version**

You can just sort on the helper column and the highest version will be at the end of the list.  Or, you can do a lookup to post the result to a cell.  The formula in H9:

```
=INDEX(A2:A7,MATCH(MAX(H2:H7),H2:H7,0))
```

This locates the maximum value in the helper column and displays the version number for the same row.

Just to show that this isn't simply picking the last value, here is the example with the original data, plus version 3.7, with the version 3.11d buried in the middle:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You're going to have to break it into pieces to compare mixed values and characters. Assuming you'll only ever have one character at the end, you can compare the `LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-1)` to the `LEFT(A2,LEN(A2)-1)` to see if you can determine a winner yet, and if they match, then check the RIGHT single letter and find a winner there.

For example:

```
=IF(LEFT(A2,LEN(A2)-1) = LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-1), (RIGHT(A2,1) > RIGHT(A1,1)), (LEFT(A2,LEN(A2)-1) > LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-1)))
```

[image]

If you had the 3.1a and 3.11d, the simple > comparison would give you the wrong answer.

Comment: You're on the right track, but try adding 3.7 in A5.

Answer (score 0):

**You can solve the issue by using Helper Column:**

[image]

- Formula in Cell `C3` & fill it down.

  `=LOOKUP(2,1/(COUNTIF(A3:A4,">"&A3:A4)=0),A3:A4)`
- In Cell `D3` write this Formula & Fill it down.

  ```
  =IF(C3>A3,"Ver "&C3&" Greater",IF(C3=A3,"Ver "&C3&" Similar","Ver "&C3&" Smaller"))
  ```

*Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.*